# Xcode: Build app on two connected phones

Tags: iphone, xcode, compilation

I want to install an app on two phones without plugging and unplugging the devices. Can this be done?

As far as I can tell, the Xcode interface does not have that functionality...

Comment: There should be an option on the build settings drop down to select a target.  If both of your phones are listed as targets, you can just pick whichever you want without unplugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean you want to install on both devices - compilation is done on the computer.

I haven't tried with two iPhones yet, but I regularly have two different iOS devices connected simultaneously via USB (two separate cables), and it works great. I can chose the device I want to install/run on via the popup menu that you can also use to select Debug/Release config and architecture. What is *not* working is installing on both at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually waiting for that comment. Too lazy to edit ;) But I'll do that now.
Also, you are right, and I am blind. There it is in the menu :)